# GitHub not recognizing LICENSE.txt inside of docs folder

Tags: github

At my [repository](https://github.com/KnowledgeableKangaroo/order.js), I have a license. It is called `LICENSE.txt` and is in the docs folder.

However, in `Insights > Community`, it doesn't have a check-mark for having a license.
In Issues and Pull Requests, it is not under helpful resources.

I don't want to move it to the root directory because I want to keep it organized.

Is there a way I can configure using Git or using GitHub that I can point the license to `docs/License.txt`?

Comment: It only detects license file in the root

Comment: Does that mean it HAS to be in the root folder?

Comment: Yes if you want it be shown on the home page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "[Adding a license to a repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-license-to-a-repository)" mentions:

> In the file name field, type `LICENSE` or `LICENSE.md` (with all caps).

So `LICENSE.txt` might not qualify.
... and, yes, there is no mention of a `docs` folder in "[About community profiles for public repositories](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-community-profiles-for-public-repositories)".
Git itself has no notion/concept of "LICENSE": it just manages file history.